# Hexo | I add a Echarts chart in my article,but it only Show on homepage，when i click `read more` it gone

Tags: javascript, hexo

about the Hexo blog question(theme is icarus）

Add the following code directly to the article(xxxx.md)

```
<div id="container" style="width:1000px;height:900px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"src="./js/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/echarts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
//add some chart into div.container
</script>
```

help help me ,ty

Comment: hi  please explain what you need   ,   do you need  this inside code editor in your post, or what

Comment: I want to add a charts(Baidu Echarts , https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) into my post,so i add some script into my post ,but the charts only show in the homepage,when i click (read more),the charts gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved,becauce Should be like this：

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="/js/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/echarts.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is my first question on this site，Although it is not a problem